# How to deploy Windows Image to different Computers(different hardware)

Tags: windows, windows-installation, disk-image

I install and reinstall windows all day. I clone to expediate the process, if the hardware allows it, but would really save a lot of time if I could just restore a windows image with all the apps installed on it. I have a Windows image I got from sysprep although I am unsure if it is deployable to a bootable iso.

Any ideas?

Any solution which allows me to deploy my windows image ( with all of my apps installed and settings enabled) to wildly different hardware would work for me.

Comment: The question is whether Windows has built-in all the drivers for all possible hardware, or not. Are you deploying using USB external disks?

Comment: I don't mind Adding the drivers later on. Yes, i am using usb sticks for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative would be to clone the system disk.

You could create your
standard installation, take an image of the system disk with a product
that has a boot media for restoring, then just boot on each target
and restore the disk.

The product must support differing disk sizes for the restore.
Most missing device drivers will be installed when the target computer
boots, if there is a connection to the internet.

My favorite product is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html)
with its
[AOMEI Bootable Media](https://www.ubackup.com/help/create-bootable-disk.html),
but there exist alternate products.

Comment: I have been doing this as a workaround for a while for now. Coincidentally, I have been using AOEMI products too.

Comment: You could also clone the system disks on dedicated hardware, then implant disks in computers, rather than installing Windows. Some large companies do it this way because it's faster.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can use the windows Image you get from DISM into a bootable iso. Works perfectly for my needs.

https://theitbros.com/sysprep-windows-machine/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/deploy-windows-mdt/deploy-a-windows-10-image-using-mdt

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/windows-10-deployment-tools-reference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc786442(v=ws.10)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/osd/understand/introduction-to-operating-system-deployment

Official Microsoft (supported) ways. There are many other ways to do the same using some disk clone software and sysprep (to generate new SID).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).